# Windows 7 PC knocking sound coming from DVD drive after boot

Tags: windows-7, dvd, noise

I have an HP Slimline Desktop PC which I installed Windows 7 from scratch. So it should be free of bloatware. I also added an SSD. I noticed that after booting, it occasionally has some knocking sound. It goes like "got-got", a few seconds later, another "got-got'. And usually heard continuously for the first 5 minutes after boot.

I finally decided to investigate where the knocking sound come from. I pulled the power from the empty, internal DVD burner and this time the PC boots up and remains quiet. The drive is TS-H653R.

I am wondering what would have caused the DVD drive to move even when there is no disc inside? Is it checking for disc? Is there a way to make it quiet without physically disconnecting it from power?

Comment: In order to distinguish hardware or software problem, you may disable the DVD drive in `Device Manager`, and boot your PC again.

Comment: Good tip! After disabling the device, noise is only heard during boot and no more noise after Windows boot up. Seems like a software issue.

Comment: I spoke too soon. I still hear the knocking sound but it is definitely a lot less after disabling it from Device Manager.